# Redirect to View(ActionResult) with complex object as paremeter from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to perform following operation.

1. On a button click from View1, do Ajax request and get complex object as return.
2. Pass this object to View2 as parameter.
3. Process the data sent from view1 in client side(inside $(window).load()).

Below is my code:

**View1 :**

```
        var Url = baseUrl() + "/InteractiveReport/GetRatingProfitData/";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "html",
           // dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "Projects": SelectedProjectinfo }),
            success: function (JsonData) {
                debugger;
                var w = window.open('about:blank');
                w.document.open();
                w.document.write(JsonData);
                w.document.close();


            },
            error: function (retVal) {
                alert("error:" + retVal.responseText);
            }
        });
```

**InteractiveReportController :**

```
public ActionResult RatingProfitReport(ProfitRatingInfoModel RatingProfitData)
{
    return View("RatingProfitReport", RatingProfitData);
}


public ActionResult GetRatingProfitData(IRSelectedProjectInfoModel Projects)
{
    ProfitRatingInfoModel RatingProfitData = new ProfitRatingInfoModel();

    //GET RatingProfitData  from Database

     return RatingProfitReport(RatingProfitDataMdl);

    //var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    //string response = jsonSerializer.Serialize(RatingProfitDataMdl);
    //return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View2 :**

```
@using Enterprise_Dashboard.Models
@model ProfitRatingInfoModel

<script>

    //Control not entering this section
    $(document).ready(function () {
        init_bind_rating_profit_table();        
    });

    function init_bind_rating_profit_table()
    {
        debugger; 
        var RatingProfitData = @Model.ProfitRatingData;
        alert(RatingProfitData[0].BU);
    }
</script>
```

Is there any better way to redirect to different view from Ajax call with parameters.

from my View1, if i directly make Ajax call to View2, i cannot pass complex object as parameter, since its too big string.

Is there any way i can set `RatingProfitDataMdl` into **Session** or **ViewBag** or **ViewData** or anything else and i can access it in **View2**?

OR

Is there any way i can eliminate Ajax call on button click so button click on View1 will automatically call `GetRatingProfitData` and it internally redirects to `RatingProfitReport` with modal object parameter?
OR

Completely different approach available to handle this scenario?

Comment: why dont you try `return RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName", model);` using `RedirectToAction` you can return model to `view2` right?

Comment: IF you want the same in `View1`, keep it in `TempData[]`

Comment: IMHO Redirect to action is the best solution here. If you can't change the first method maybe you can write one method that combines both. If you decide to go with TempData just remember that in Core 2.0 TempData values are stored in cookies on the client machine. In Net Famework TempData internally uses session to store the data thus the data must be serialized.

Comment: if i use `RedirectToAction`, it will show Ajax error saying TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. i am calling GetRatingProfitData from ajax call and it expects some response in return.